# How to autoflush in Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2, and would like this ORM to auto `flush()` the EntityManager before executing any `SELECT` query, to ensure consistency at all times within the application (this application is abstracting a lot, and should not have any knowledge of the EntityManager, apart from inside the Repositories).

Is there an option to do that with Doctrine?

If not, any strategy to implement this easily?

Comment: Kind of an interesting question. I'd like to know that as well.

Comment: Build a service, call the service, build query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've found so far, is to manually `flush()` before issuing a `SELECT` query in the repository methods that *must not* return stale data:

```php
class OrderRepository
{
   public function findByUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->em->flush();

        $query = $this->em->createQuery( ... );

        // ...
    }
}
```

This way, the flush is hidden from the services that consume the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to flush (write changes) before all selects? Is it possible that you require transactional consistency? ie, will an insert / update be dependent on the results of a previous select? In which case i'd suggest using an explicit transaction, like so:

```
$em->transactional(function($em) {
    $entity = $em->find('Entity', 123);
    if ($entity->getValue() > 2)
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->setName('George');
        $em->persist($user);
    }
});
```

If not, i'd suggest sticking with the default set up and let the unitOfWork stack up and optimise insertions / updates toward the end of your runtime.

Comment: That's the opposite, actually. The SELECT needs to take into account an entity modified in memory. But this select is encapsulated in a Repository, itself called by a Service. The Service does a lot of very abstract work, and can not (read: *should* not) deal with low-level objects such as the EntityManager. Hibernate, the Java open-source ORM which inspired Doctrine, has auto-flush enabled by default when a transaction is active.

Comment: "The SELECT needs to take into account an entity modified in memory" - again this sounds like you need transactional integrity. Its possible to inspect your changeset and work out if there is anything relevant to the select your doing. $em->getUnitOfWork()->computeChangeSets(); $insertions = $em->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions(); Not sure if that's any help though.

Comment: By "modified in memory", I don't mean scheduled for insertion, I mean a property change on an existing entity. This has nothing to do with transational integrity anyway, it's do to with the Repository not returning stale data within my transaction. What you propose is more complicated than what I ask, and does not solve the problem (no offense)!

Comment: A property change on an existing entity (managed) will be added to the unit of work change set (as an update), so you can still access it that way. But your right, it'll certainly become a complicated solution.

Comment: Actually, I already have a working solution: calling `flush()` at the beginning of each of my Repository methods. So the changes will be synced to the database, and the result of the queries will reflect the current in-memory status of the objects. This is an error-prone methodology, however, and I'd be happy to find a more generic solution.